# Nginx - proxy_pass to google storage bucket does not use the index directive

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-storage, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set my root(/) location to be passed to a google bucket.

Here is my configuration:

```
    listen 80;      
    location / {                
            rewrite /(.*) /$1       break;
            proxy_pass              https://storage.googleapis.com/my-google-bucket-name/$1$is_args$args;
            proxy_redirect          off;
            index                   my_main.html;
            proxy_set_header        Host "storage.googleapis.com";
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header        Connection "upgrade";
    }
```

This seems to work but the **index** directive does not set the default page (to my_main.html)

e.g. when i go to http://my_enginx_url/ instead of reaching "my_main.html" i reach the google bucket root page that shows an XML file with all the files in that bucket.

P.S
Both

http://my_enginx_url/another_page.html,

http://my_enginx_url/yet_another_page.html

are working fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `index` directive tells Nginx the names of files to look for within your file system which are appropriate for serving a request ending with a `/`

You are proxying the request to another server, so it's not applicable here.

To achieve your desired result create another location directive above your current one and use `=` to tell Nginx this is to handle only requests for an exact match with http://my_enginx_url/

Something like this:

```
location = / {
    proxy_pass https://storage.googleapis.com/my-google-bucket-name/my_main.html;
    ......
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you.