# Nginx - proxy_pass to google storage bucket static page VueJS sub paths cause 404 error, VueJS router not kicking in

Tags: vue.js, nginx, google-cloud-storage, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm hosting VueJS at google cloud storage bucket, app works only when using domain name without subpath: `www.domain.com` when using URL like: `www.domain.com/sub/path` I'm getting 404 error as it seem that NGINX is looking for this path in the bucket instead of let VueJS router take over.
I tried to follow older [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51156523/nginx-proxy-pass-to-google-storage-bucket-does-not-use-the-index-directive/51161146#51161146) but in my case would not help.

Any ideas how to fix this?

```
   location = / {
       proxy_pass https://gcs/mygoogle-cloud-bucket/main.html;
       proxy_set_header Host storage.googleapis.com;
   }
   location / {
       rewrite /(.*) /$1 break;
       proxy_pass https://gcs/mygoogle-cloud-bucket/$1$is_args$args;
       proxy_redirect off;
       index main.html;
       proxy_set_header Host storage.googleapis.com;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you need to do is to create a [Static Website](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website) using Cloud Storage and VueJS.

With this bieng the case, there are a few things that needs to be clarified:

- Cloud Storage doesn't support HTTPs, so yo uneed to use a [Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https).
- Make sure the objects in your bucket are [public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#objects).
- Build the [Vue project With Relative Path](https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-host-a-vue-js-static-website-with-gcp-cloud-storage-b8e87b89e4de#:%7E:text=We%20need%20to%20add%20the%20following%20entry%20in%20the%20file%20called%20vue.config.js).
- It is also recomended to set the [special pages](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#specialty-pages), but this is not necessary.
- Set up your load balancer and the SSL certificate as it is mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#lb-ssl).
- Configure [routing rules](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#lb-host).
- Make sure you have [connected your custom domain to your load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#connect-domain)

This should get you going with your site. If you would like to check a worknig example, you can take a look at [this one](https://github.com/presslabs/gs-proxy).

Your code should look something like:

```
 location / {
            rewrite /$ $uri$index_name;

            proxy_set_header    Host storage.googleapis.com;
            proxy_pass          https://gs/$bucket_name$uri;
            proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_set_header    Connection "";
        }
```